# How to remove dashes from object namespace, generated by openapi 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, azure-api-management, openapi

I use `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (v4.0.1)` to generate `swagger.json` file in asp .net core. After the import in Azure API Management we see the following types that we don't expect:
 `SwaggerGenerationSample-Models-EmployeeArray` and `SwaggerGenerationSample-Models-EmployeeArray-1` etc. .

I expect to have dots instead of dashes `SwaggerGenerationSample.Models.EmployeeArray`.

I tried to use

```
CustomSchemaIds(t => t.Name), instead of CustomSchemaIds(t => t.FullName)
```

but don't work due to some duplicated object names `(Request.Employee and Response.Employee).`

I currently have the following configuration in AspNetCore.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(config => {
   config.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
   config.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName);
   config.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "SampleAPI", Version = "v1" });
   config.MapType<decimal>(() => new Schema { Type = "number", Format = "double" });
   config.MapType<decimal?>(() => new Schema { Type = "number", Format = "double" });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe , this is because of the recent changes how Open API import and export works in APIM. You can find the semantics [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md) as it aligns with it.

Here is the normalization rule for the same:

Normalization rules for operationId

- Convert to lower case.
- Replace each sequence of non-alphanumeric characters with a single dash, e.g. `GET-/foo/{bar}?buzz={1}` will be transformed into `get-foo-bar-buzz-1-`.
- Trim dashes on both sides, e.g. `get-foo-bar-` will become `get-foo-bar`
- Truncate to fit 76 characters, four characters less than maximum limit for a resource name.
- Use remaining four characters for a deduplication suffix, if necessary, in the form of -1, -2, …, -999.

You can read more about it [here](https://blog.tomkerkhove.be/2018/04/13/changes-to-azure-api-management-openapi/):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/apimanagement/2018/04/11/important-changes-to-openapi-import-and-export/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Where exactly in the document can I find the information that is related to the issue above?

Comment: https://blog.tomkerkhove.be/2018/04/13/changes-to-azure-api-management-openapi/ Check this

Comment: I see the article and your answer is mainly referring to methods. The issue that I face is that it's applicable when we have an Array/IEnumerable with a complex type as return type (with Array1, Array2 as a suffix).

Comment: if it's not a trouble, will you be able to share the code base, will take a look. Yes it talks about method.

Comment: I created a Github repo with a demo project that reproduces the issue I'm facing https://github.com/mvdiemen/SwaggerArrayGenerationExample. When you import the swagger.json in APIM you will see that there are Arrays generated (Array1, Array 2) etc. that we don't expect.

Comment: After import , where do you want me to look?, Can you send the screenshot. Let me start the personal chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198547/discussion-between-mohit-verma-and-mrtentje).